# c++ dynamically loading dll error

Tags: c++, dll, cmake, dynamic-loading

I am trying to generate a **.dll** and then with another application I check if it can be used correctly.

However, `LoadLibrary` gives me error, and when I check the **.dll** with dependency walker, it gives me this error:

"At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module."

This happens when I try to use one object. Actually, I am totally lost and do not know how to do that. Let me explain:

- I have some sources of codes in C++ that I can not modify. They are compiled as STATIC libraries.
- Then, my task is, to generate a **.dll**, and one **.h** so that the clients  could use the **.dll**.

So, the idea isn't that I need to put functions in **.h**, export it, and declare them in **.cpp** of my project that generate **.dll** using other codes that I can not modify?

What I have done for my very first try is:

Let say that I have:

**Project 1:** someApi.hpp (class SomeAPI), someApi.cpp

**DLL Project:** interace.h, interface.cpp, + include Project 1.

**Client Project to test DLL:** main.cpp, interface.h

```
/** interface.h **/

#include <windows.h>

#ifdef MY_DLL_lib_EXPORTS
#define DLL_API extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLL_API extern "C" __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

DLL_API int WINAPI myfirsttry();

/** interface.cpp **/

#include "interface.h"
#include "someApi.hpp"

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HANDLE h, DWORD r, LPVOID l) {
    switch (r) {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return true;
}

DLL_API int WINAPI myfirsttry() { 
    SomeAPI someAPI;  // When I comment this, LoadLibrary does not give error.

    return 0; 
}


/** main.cpp **/

#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include "interface.h"

int main() {
    HINSTANCE dll;
    dll = LoadLibrary(L"D:\\myLib.dll"); // Sure that route is correct as other valid dll can be loaded
    if (!dll) {
        std::cout << "NOT OK" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

/*******************************/
Output: NOT OK
/*******************************/
```

I compile my dll with cmake using `add_library(${NAME} SHARED ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})`

I know that I miss lots of things here as I have told that I am lost. Could you please have a look?

Comment: How about calling [`GetLastError`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx) when the [`LoadLibrary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx) function fails, to know what the error really is?

Comment: Didn't you forget to `#define MY_DLL_lib_EXPORTS` in your dll project?

Comment: @k.v. No:( Also I have checked that if the definition works.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it gives me 127: ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND.
So does it mean that it does not see any exported function?

Comment: EDIT:  I had forgotten "SomeAPI someAPI;" line in the question. When I comment it, it is OK. That line is the source of problem.

Comment: Then please open your freshly created DLL with dependency_walker (http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to find out what DLL dependency is missing.

Comment: Just noticed you already did run DependencyWalker for your DLL. Can you attach the full output of the error messages or a picture of DependencyWalker window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it was because the application was loading different version of **libstdc++-6** than the **.dll** needed. Copying that the right version of it manually in the folder of executable solved the problem. I have used **dumpbin** to see all dependencies.